# How to handle timestamp with timezone on postgres with knex.js

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I am trying to translate following sql query into knex:

```
select count(*) as finished_on_time from task_history 
where  date = 20160303 
       and store_id = 2 
       and (schedule_start_time at time zone 'Australia/sydney' + interval '1' minute * floor (group_duration) )::time >= (finish_time at time zone 'Australia/sydney')::time
```

- date field has in yyyymmdd format

Here is what I have been trying on knex:

```
db.table('task_history')
.count('*')
.where({date: request.params.storeid, store_id: request.params.storeid }) 
??????
```

As you can guess, I am not sure which clause to use to handle sql syntax [at time zone `Australia/sydney`].

I have been trying to find any similar soloutions on the internet, but ended up here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://knexjs.org/#Builder-whereRaw

```
db.table('task_history')
    .count('*')
    .where({date: request.params.storeid, store_id: request.params.storeid })
    .whereRaw("(schedule_start_time at time zone 'Australia/sydney' + interval '1' minute * floor (group_duration) )::time >= (finish_time at time zone 'Australia/sydney')::time")
```